# Horizontal uitableview with screen edge swipe gesture

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have a view which looks like this:

[image]

I implemented this view with two horizontal uitableview. So all promotions under certain category actually is in a table view which allow user to swipe left and right to change category. On the left top there is a button which opens a side view. Now I want to add a screen edge gesture to open the side view but it seems the screen edge gesture conflicts with the table view scrolling gesture.

So where should I do if I want to implement the screen edge gesture without disabling tableview's scroll gesture?

Thanks!

Comment: May I know how do you do the horizontal swipe category under the navigation bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your gesture delegate in your viewcontroller class, and use this delegate method :

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES ;
}
```